# Problem with 1st order Massberg LPF

Tags: matlab, filter-design, lowpass-filter, octave

I'm trying to implement this filter in title by following the book "[Designing Audio Effect Plug-Ins in C++](https://books.google.fi/books?id=QddcxHLavrMC&pg=PA201&lpg=PA204#v=onepage&q&f=false)" By Will Pirkle

Problem I'm facing is the magnitude response error when comparing against analog model of the LP filter. Here is a plot showing the difference.

[image]

I get these are values for variables (fc=1000, fs=44100):

```
>> massberg_test

    w0 =  0.14248
    g1 =  0.045305
    gm =  0.70711
    wm =  6283.2
    Om =  0.071359
    Os =  0.10081
    g0 =  1.1008
    a0 =  0.14612
    a1 =  0.055508
    b1 = -0.89919
Real:
    a = [ 0.132736  0.050424 ]
    b = [ 1.00000  -0.81684 ]
```

I don't have access to the [original paper by M. Massberg](http://www.aes.org/e-lib/browse.cfm?elib=16077) so, I can't be sure if the equations in my source book is correct (I've read that the "ac" in g1 formula is just a typo and book errata does not mention other errors for this fileter).

Q: 
1. Are the equations found in Pirkle book correct?
2. If 1 is Yes then where to look the issue from?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved.

Looks like calculation of `Os` ($\omega_s$) was the culprit for this problem. Proper equation is:

```
Os=Om*sqrt((gm^2-g1^2)*(1-gm^2))/(1-gm^2);
```

instead of:

```
Os=Om*(sqrt((gm^2-g1^2)*(1-gm^2))/(1-gm^2));
```